# Invalid request to Eventbrite. Eventbrite Authorisation Request

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, oauth, eventbrite

I'm trying to develop an App in PHP that connects to Eventbright via the Eventbrite plugin for WordPress, and connect it to an Evenbright user account that is localised to New Zealand.

The connection login is being blocked by recent redirects put in by Eventbrite to go .com -> .nz

I'll create a new account now only in USA to test this shortly to get around this regional redirect breakage... and so I can continue some work, but posting this so perhaps the developers of the WordPress plugin I'm using can have a look.

My app asks for URL [1] which then redirects through [2] and [3]. After a successful login with tom@funk.co.nz we go through [4] and land on URL [5] with an error:

"Eventbrite Authorisation Request: The application you're trying to use has made an invalid request to Eventbrite. Please contact the application developer."

```
[0] http : // [my website]/wp-admin/tools.php?page=eventbrite-page
[1] http : // [my website]/wp-admin/tools.php?page=keyring&service=eventbrite&blog=1&for=eventbrite&action=request&kr_nonce=5c02dd7dd7&nonce=b01918bd21
[2] https : // [eventbrite com]/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp-admin%2Ftools.php%3Fpage%3Dkeyring%26service%3Deventbrite%26action%3Dverify%26kr_nonce%3D10a94c785b%26nonce%3D20efff0172&state=4
[3] https : // [eventbrite com]/login/?referrer=/oauth/authorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fwp-admin%252Ftools.php%253Fpage%253Dkeyring%2526service%253Deventbrite%2526action%253Dverify%2526kr_nonce%253D10a94c785b%2526nonce%253D20efff0172%26state%3D4
[4] https : // [eventbrite co nz]/international/change_locale/?locale=en_NZ&ssodata=ALL0zNqAzt_ArDsJX7BOnK_FpbwlY2apmrXwulr4ULf5uOCvKhyGBzJZ41FtJhYKJSg4vVsHm7_xzwbbBE0TZTf5QIVw9pglvg&url=https%3A//[eventbrite co nz]/oauth/authorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fwp-admin%252Ftools.php%253Fpage%253Dkeyring%2526service%253Deventbrite%2526action%253Dverify%2526kr_nonce%253D10a94c785b%2526nonce%253D20efff0172%26state%3D4%26internal_ref%3Dlogin&lang=en-au
[5] https : // [eventbrite co nz]/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp-admin%2Ftools.php%3Fpage%3Dkeyring%26service%3Deventbrite%26action%3Dverify%26kr_nonce%3D10a94c785b%26nonce%3D20efff0172&state=4&internal_ref=login
```